# KeyError: "[Column] not found in axis"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If a column exists between 2 dataframes, I want to drop it. I check if it exists and then try to drop it, but then it says that can't be found.

```
for column in positionsdf.columns:
    if column in entrydf.columns:
        entrydf = entrydf.drop(column)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d9893719abf8> in <module>
      1 for column in positionsdf.columns:
      2     if column in entrydf.columns:
----> 3         entrydf = entrydf.drop(column)

...
...
...

KeyError: "['caseworker'] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame#drop` defaults to the row axis. You want to drop a column. Use syntax:

```
df.drop(columns=[columns, input, here])
```

You can also get rid of reassignment by passing parameter `inplace=True`.